# What's the difference between a fiber node and fiber in React?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, react-fiber

I'm beginning to grasp the concepts around React's fiber architecture and the data structures that it uses.

But I keep seeing the phrases "fiber node" and "fiber" used interchangeably and also sometimes referring to different concepts.

Are these referring to the exact same thing or slight differences in the representational data structures that are being used in the algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: I tend to think of "Fiber" proper as the React difference engine which lets it efficiently update.  A "Fiber Node" is an instance in the Fiber component tree which gets translated into the browser DOM.  I've seen folks refer to a node as just a "fiber" which makes things confusing.

Comment: @possum Yeah, I think my understanding is leaning that way too. It's a little weird that the most common SEO'd articles have their own way of describing those terms.